# Android contact list with contact information

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is there anyone who implemented android contact list same as written at https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html? I have some problems with understanding this source code

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        // Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity
        mContactsList =
            (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contact_list_view);
        // Gets a CursorAdapter
        mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.contact_list_item,
                null,
                FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS,
                0);
        // Sets the adapter for the ListView
        mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is code line you don't understand?

Comment: Where to put this void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)? Inside of onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)? Why we need contact_list_view? Is this LinearLayout?

Comment: Because onActivityCreated  is called after the Activity's onCreate() has completed. It is called after onCreateView(), and is mainly used for final initialisations (for example, modifying UI elements). And we need contact_list_view to show list contact on Screen and it's not LinearLayout , it's ListView

Comment: What is the difference between contacts_list_view and contact_list_view?